# Уточняющий оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно выделить оборот *от запорного до регулирующего*? Я так понимаю, он является несогласованным определением? Изначально в тексте стояли две запятые.

1. При необходимости УЗДА способна работать в любом режиме, от запорного до регулирующего, не теряя при этом ни одного из своих потребительских качеств.
2. При необходимости УЗДА способна работать в любом режиме — от запорного до регулирующего — не теряя при этом ни одного из своих потребительских качеств.

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд выделение запятыми показалось верным. Но нашла объяснение, которое очень подходит к Вашему тексту:
"Уточняющие члены при подчеркивании смысла выделяются или отделяются тире: Они [статуи] были расставлены прямо на земле и на газонах – без пьедесталов – в каком-то продуманном беспорядке (Кат.) – уточняется обстоятельство; Мины же все в снегу, который тут совсем неглубокий – до щиколотки (В. Бык.) – уточняется сказуемое; Памятников, правда, было мало – всего пять-шесть (Пауст.) – уточнение в нерасчлененном односоставном предложении".

Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации: Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина. – М., 2011, § 79, прим., в разделе «Знаки препинания при уточняющих, пояснительных и присоединительных членах предложения», с. 221–222.

Но после слова "регулирующего" тоже нужно поставить запятую.

Comment: Т. е. предложение будет иметь такой вид? При необходимости УЗДА способна работать в любом режиме — от запорного до регулирующего, — не теряя при этом ни одного из своих потребительских качеств. Запятой отделяем следующий дальше деепричастный оборот?

Comment: Да, я думаю так. Но подождите ещё, что скажут знатоки.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое.

Answer (score 1):

Это уточняющее  несогласованное определение, выраженное словосочетанием, возможны оба варианта обособления:

При необходимости УЗДА способна работать в любом режиме, от запорного до регулирующего, не теряя при этом ни одного из своих потребительских качеств.

При необходимости УЗДА способна работать в любом режиме — от запорного до регулирующего, — не теряя при этом ни одного из своих потребительских качеств.

Варианты различаются интонацией, при обособлении тире это вставочная интонация (увеличенные паузы, пониженный тон речи), добавочный характер сообщения. Два тире и перенесенная запятая.

Comment: Спасибо большое. А мне казалось, что "от... до" предполагает тире. И за запятую спасибо.